# Failed to return new code element, Possible syntax error

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, classwizard

I have 2 radio button under a group box and i made first one group as true. but when i am adding radio button variable the it showing message "Failed to return new code element possibly a syntax error", what would be the reason?

Comment: I have run into a similar problem with the ATL wizard of Visual Studio 2005 in which using the Add Method wizard from Class View to add a method to an interface failed with this message.  Using the answer below of deleting the Intellisense file (.ncb) worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the Class Wizard file (.clw) and the Intellisense file (.ncb) file from your solution directory and try again.

Comment: I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2005 when creating an C++ ATL control.  I deleted the Intellisense file (.ncb) from the solution directory and after reopening the project the Add Method wizard in the Class View started working.  Thanks loads!

Answer (score 3):

I meet this issue on VS 2022. I solved it by these steps:

1. closing VS solution.
2. delete .vs directory
3. re-open *.sln

Comment: works on VS2019 too

Answer (score 0):

You need to have only one variable for your data and one for your control for your grouped Controls:

```
int m_RBData;
CRadio m_RBControl;
```

Then you need to group all ID Controls within the linked function like this:

ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED,IDC_RB,IDC_RB3,OnClickRb)

You also need to add reference to String Table:

1R__C 0,1,2 in your first ID (IDC_RB).

Now your data variable, takes the values 0,1 or 2 whenever you click the first, the second or the third radio button respectively.